# Not found drawer layout

Tags: java, android, dependencies, android-videoview

When I add exoplayer dependency then my project gives an error "

cannot access DrawerLayout

public class allow_access extends AppCompatActivity {

```
   ^
```

class file for androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout not found" even I don't used drawer layout when I remove exoplayer dependency it's work fine.

When I add exoplayer dependency my project gives error. About drawer layout even I don't used it.